# PHP - if conditional statement skipped unless an else is specified

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I created a very simple login page where I validate the username and password on PHP after submitting the form.

My first step in the validation is to check that the username and password are not empty, if empty I send the user back to the login page:

```
$e = $_POST['email'];
$p = $_POST['password'];


if($e == '' || $p == ''  || is_null($e) || is_null($p)){
    header('Location: login.php?e=missing');
}
```

it turns out that the `if` statement that checks if the username and password are empty only works if I add an `else` statement:

```
$e = $_POST['email'];
$p = $_POST['password'];


if($e == '' || $p == ''  || is_null($e) || is_null($p)){
    header('Location: login.php?e=missing');
}else{

    //more validation
}
```

To be honest, my code works, I added the `else` and problem solved, but WHY???
Thanks.

Comment: I would consider a adding a little validation

Comment: Worth pointing out, as well, that your second example has two more checks: the `is_null` function on the `$e` and `$p` vars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$e = $_POST['email'];
$p = $_POST['password'];


if(trim($e) == '' || trim($p) == ''){
    header('Location: login.php?e=missing');
    exit(); // add this else it wont leave the page!
}else{

    //more validation
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `empty()` function to test if a variable is "empty."

Comment: This is true - didn't think of that - would be better than == ''

Comment: isn't header() supposed to exit everything as well?

Comment: Doesn't always. I have found that if you don't put exit(); directly after the header, it will continue processing the code that follows then produce a headers already sent error

Answer (score 1):

```
if($e == '' || $p == ''){
    header('Location: login.php?e=missing');
}
```

You need to add an `exit()` after the header line; otherwise, processing continues as normal and all the rest of the code is run.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `empty` to check if the variables are set, as well as empty.

```
 $e = $_POST['email'];
 $p = $_POST['password'];

 if( empty($e) || empty($p) )     {
   header('Location: login.php?e=missing');  
   exit;  
}
else {
//more validation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$e = $_POST['email'];
$p = $_POST['password'];

if(!empty($e) && !empty($p))
{
    header('Location: login.php?e=missing');
    exit();
}
else
{
    //more validation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($e == '' || $p == ''){
        header('Location: login.php?e=missing');
    }
```

rathen then that use :

```
if(!isset($e) || !isset($p)){
    header('Location: login.php?e=missing');
    exit();
}
```

**It is happens because of white space or you can use trim() function to remove white space and use exit(); after header its mandatory***